# .Net Maui. How to pass value from Page1 to Page2 using services.AddTransient

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, maui

I want to pass an argument from Page1 to Page2. I'm using the MVVM pattern with the help of CommunityToolkit. In my Page1ViewModel, I'm using RelayCommand to navigate to Page2.

Code:

```
[RelayCommand]
private async Task GoToEditPage(int id)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("editPage");
}
```

I have register in MauiProgram:

builder.Services.AddTransient();

I have to use id in Page2 through Page2ViewModel.
How to do that?
I'm trying t

```
[RelayCommand]
private async Task GoToEditPage(int idPass)
{

    var editViewModel = ServiceHelper.GetService<Page2ViewModel>();
    editViewModel.Initialize(idPass);
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("edit");
}

public partial class Page2ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] private int passID;

    public void Initialize(int passID)
    {
        PassID = passID;
    }


public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = Helpers.ServiceHelper.GetService<Page2ViewModel>();
}

public static class ServiceHelper
{
    public static TService GetService<TService>()
        => Current.GetService<TService>();

    public static IServiceProvider Current =>
#if WINDOWS10_0_17763_0_OR_GREATER
            MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Services;
#elif ANDROID
            MauiApplication.Current.Services;
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
            MauiUIApplicationDelegate.Current.Services;
#else
            null;
#endif
}
```

This:

```
BindingContext = Helpers.ServiceHelper.GetService<EditPassengerViewModel>();
```

Result id: Null

I'm unsure how to access the instance of Page2ViewModel that will already contain my ID. I need the value to be available directly in the ViewModel, so passing the value through QueryProperty is not an option for me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: No. No. And No. From all the bad design choices, this one surely takes one of the top spots. There are many ways to pass data, this page shows some of them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data. I recommend this part: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-a-single-method. There are many ways to get the job done, but this what you are trying to do is crossing-the-line-wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to H.A.H.'s comment, you can get ways to pass value from Page1 to Page2 by referring to the [official documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/).

See this page: [.NET MAUI Shell navigation -> Pass data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data), and this method: 
[Process navigation data using a single method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#process-navigation-data-using-a-single-method).